# Hangouts sends notifications to all my devices, all the time

Tags: google-hangouts

I do not know if it is a feature or an issue. Maybe I am not seeing this situation as I should. My problem is that I have Hangouts on my Mac at home with Chrome Extension (Mac OS X 10.10), at my office PC with Chrome Extension (Elementary OS (Ubuntu based)) and in my phone (iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.3); and everytime someone writes me on Hangouts I receive the notification on these 3 devices. I find a bit annoying that when I am at the office chatting on Hangouts, my phone keeps ringing/vibrating because of notifications. Plus, at home anyone using the Mac can see the notifications and the conversation.

It is not a matter of "privacy" (not that I do not want anyone at home reading my Hangouts). It is a matter of "annoyance". Shouldn't it stop sending notifications and just send it to the last one being used or the active one? Is this an issue that just I am experiencing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Short-term solution

Manually disable/enable notifications for *"Web and desktop"* or *"Mobile"* in *Settings* every time your needs change:

> Sitting down to do some work? Change the settings. Going for a cup of
>   coffee? Change the settings. Going to a meeting? Change the settings.
>   Leaving work? Change the settings.

### Long-term solution

For Hangouts Chat, Google should take a lesson from their competitor Slack which has implemented this and similar features in far better way. One can hope Google steps up their notification game to address such concerns.

#### Single-device notifications

Notifications are *not* sent to mobile devices while one is active on desktop. The amount of time one has to be inactive before receiving notifications can be customized to ones liking.

["When I'm not active on desktop …" preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jGRn.png)

#### Do Not Disturb

Furthermore, one can customize time slots where notifications will be disabled. With this one avoids notifications at given times.

["Do Not Disturb" preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BswCl.png)

#### Notify me about …

It is also possible to determine what kind of messages you will receive a notification for. This also ensures that the amount of notifications are kept to a desired level.

["Notify me about …" preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ervjx.png)

*Clarification: I am in no way affiliated with any of the chat services. I am simply a user with some experience using both solutions, who have grown annoyed by notifications on Hangouts Chat.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying situation. What I did: clic on "Options" in the chat window and uncheck "Notifications", then "Save". Now when this person talks to you, the only notification will be on the tab of the browser. I did it only with people I talk to frecuently everyday, if someone else is talking to me, I want notifications for sure.